# android application not being downloaded onto device when running in android studio

Tags: android

In android studio when I run my application on a device, it does not get installed onto the device like it used to. Meanwhile all of my other applications get installed onto the device when I run them. Any reason as to why this may be? I already have "Deploy default APK" selected in the Run/Debug Configurations so it can't be that. Any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

nvm, turns out my manifest's action android:name=""  tag had my package's name specified instead of "android.intent.action.MAIN" and that's what was causing the issue. Silly me.